# ILI9163C screen not working properly

Tags: display

I've just tried out my new TFT_ILI9163C display with [TFT_ILI9163C](https://github.com/sumotoy/TFT_ILI9163C) library but I'm having an issue with it. The graphics has moved down (the "hello world" should be in the top left) and the leftover space looks like there was no signal. Can be seen in the photo.
What could be wrong?

[image: looks kind of no signal]

Comment: Have you read the section entitled "BLACK, RED or ..." in your link above?

Comment: Arduino\libraries\TFT_ILI9163C\_settings\TFT_ILI9163C_settings.h
Change value here... #define __OFFSET 0//*see note 2

Answer (score 3):

I had the same board and problem as you, what fixed is was changing the board setting to black even though it is phyiscally red.

Inside

```
Arduino\libraries\TFT_ILI9163C\_settings\TFT_ILI9163C_settings.h
```

Change

```
//  ---> SELECT HERE <----
#define __144_RED_PCB__//128x128
//#define __144_BLACK_PCB__//128x128
//#define __22_RED_PCB__//240x320
```

to

```
//  ---> SELECT HERE <----
//#define __144_RED_PCB__//128x128
#define __144_BLACK_PCB__//128x128
//#define __22_RED_PCB__//240x320
```

Comment: This worked but I'm unable to accept this answer. Is it due to lots of time having been spent since it was written?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own driver for DisplayCore for that very same board a while back and found the exact same problem.

The issue is just the setting for the offset of the GRAM which it looks like there is a setting for in the library you are using.  Get that value right and you will have a proper display.

Comment: I see it - but what to do with that? I'm trying to make work the benchmark example. Copied the #define stuffs but no luck so far ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file

   `{sketchbook folder}/libraries/TFT_ILI9163C/_settings/TFT_ILI9163C_settings.h`

   in a text editor. You can find the location of the sketchbook folder in the Arduino IDE at **File > Preferences > Sketchbook location**.
2. Change:

   ```
   #define __OFFSET      32
   ```

   to:

   ```
   #define __OFFSET      0
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Upload the sketch to the Arduino board again.

Comment: This was what worked for me too. Although there is a white line in the right and bottom borders now and it wasn't there before, This line is not at the top and left borders.